# Trouble with importing a JSON file into C# object

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to import a JSON file into an object in C# (VS 2017 on Mac) to do further operations on it.

I have this JSON file example:

```
{
  "subdomain": "mycompany",
  "name": "MyCompany Inc",
  "website": "https://www.mycompany.com",
  "edition": "DIRECTORY",
  "licensing":
  {
    "apps":
    [
      "boxnet"
    ]
  },
  "admin": {
    "profile":
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "email": "joe@mycompany.com",
      "login": "joe@mycompany.com",
      "mobilePhone": null
    },
    "credentials":
    {
      "password":
      {
        "value": "NotAPassword"},
        "recovery_question":
        {
          "question": "Best Solution",
          "answer": "MyOne"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I generated a C# library to create an object type to import into:

```
using System;

namespace OrgCustom
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class Licensing
    {
        public List<string> apps { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public object mobilePhone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Password
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class RecoveryQuestion
    {
        public string question { get; set; }
        public string answer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Credentials
    {
        public Password password { get; set; }
        public RecoveryQuestion recovery_question { get; set; }
    }

    public class Admin
    {
        public Profile profile { get; set; }
        public Credentials credentials { get; set; }
    }

    public class Org
    {
        public string subdomain { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }
        public string edition { get; set; }
        public Licensing licensing { get; set; }
        public Admin admin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And so, I should be able to import the file quite easily, using the Newtownsoft.Json library?

Well, my program code is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OrgCustom;

namespace TestStart
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string JSONstring = File.ReadAllText("CreateOrgExample.json");

            OrgCustom.Org objOrg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrgCustom.Org>(JSONstring);
            Console.WriteLine(objOrg.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, I get a message on the line from the Deserialize line that JsonConvert is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

What am I doing wrong here? That line I saw in the Introduction to JSON with C# MVA course and I believe that it should work?!?!

Thanks in advance,

QuietLeni

Comment: I tested on PC with VS2017 .net core 2 and it works. (after removing the last '}')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to an issue with your JSON having an extra closing bracket at the end. So you might getting error at parsing.

Comment: Thanks for this - I am not OCD enough! I did the same!

Answer (score 0):

The error you reported `JsonConvert is a type, which is not valid in the given context` has nothing to do with the fact the JSON is  malformed.

I do not see a syntax error. You might check assembly references and then use a `global::` qualifier to drill down to the convert call (but again it looks correct to me.)

As an aside, your `Password` class does not define a `RecoveryQuestion` property as is found in the JSON snippet. This shouldn't prevent Newtonsoft from deserializing the JSON snippet into the structure you do have defined, though.